# « Envisager », « Prévoir » ou « anticiper » ?

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot, formulation-idiomatique, formulation, reformulation

Avant de donner un congé prématuré à plusieurs patients et du coup de libérer plusieurs lits, peut-être que l’hôpital a

…anticipé le pire en imaginant un accroissement des cas d’infection à la COVID.

…prévu le pire en imaginant un accroissement des cas d’infection à la COVID.

…envisagé le pire en imaginant un accroissement des cas d’infection à la COVID.

Quelles seraient d’autres façons d’exprimer cette idée d’un autre style, d’une manière plus concise et de meilleure langue?

Comment: En comparant l'évolution des virus, les médecins *connaissaient* celle du SRAS-CoV-2 et *prévenu* les répliques. Ils ont organisé les services hospitaliers en conséquence et sollicité les laboratoires de vaccins.

Comment: @Personne «…X connaissaient Y et _prévenu_ (?) Z » ?

Comment: @LPH … Z n'est pas un événement/une situation/un état prévisible. Pré-venir == venir/avertir *avant*.

Comment: @Personne Oui, mais « prévenu » tout seul ? Il me semble qu'un auxiliaire soit nécessaire (ont), autrement c'est une construction qui défie toutes les notions que j'ai acquises.

Comment: @Germaine Je pensais que "du coup" était moqué au Canada francophone.

Comment: @jlliagre Il était naguère moqué mais son emploi s’est répandu ces dernières années.

Comment: @LPH … il n'est pas tout seul, il a pour sujet médecins et [il est] précédé de “ont” sous-entendu.

Comment: @jlliagre On spécule que c'était uniquement sur le Plateau Mont-Royal mais peut-être que non... https://twitter.com/perreaux/status/1325949396551340032

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plus de concision semble difficile; une meilleur mise en rapport des idées ne serait  pas un problème, et on pourrait trouver que les possibilités suivantes ont chacune leur propre mérite en ce sens. (Comme il n'est pas clair que le pire serait le manque de places plutôt que l'accroissement des cas, les deux interprétations sont considérées.)

- Il est possible que l'hôpital, en anticipation du pire, c'est à dire d'un accroissement du nombre des cas (de COVID), ait mis en convalescence prématurée un certain nombre de patients de sorte à faire de la place pour de nouveaux arrivants.
- La mise en convalescence prématurée de certains malades n'est peut-être qu'une décision prise par l'hôpital en anticipation du pire, c'est à dire d'un accroissement du nombre des cas (de COVID), ce qui autrement les forcerait à refuser des malades.
- La mise en convalescence prématurée de certains malades n'est peut-être qu'une décision prise par l'hôpital en prévention du pire, c'est à dire d'un manque de places qu'occasionnerait un accroissement du nombre des cas (de COVID).